# Loop through web service object and create drop-down

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I need to create a drop down using the data from a Web Service which gives me a JSON in the below format:

```
{
    "ErrorInfo": {
        "Success": true,
        "ErrorCode": "",
        "Program": "",
        "Method": "",
        "Message": "",
        "Details": "",
        "StackTrace": "",
        "ErrorList": null
    },
    "Results": {
        "DimName": "region",
        "SubsetName": "",
        "Members": [{
            "ID": "Central Europe",
            "Name": "Central Europe",
            "Children": [],
            "Hierarchy": [],
            "Attributes": []
        },
        {
            "ID": "Southern Europe",
            "Name": "Southern Europe",
            "Children": null,
            "Hierarchy": [],
            "Attributes": []
        }]
    }
}
```

My HTML code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <style>
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="images"></div>

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/somewebservice/json/Europe?",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: true,
    success: function (data,value) {
      var obj = JSON.stringify(data,value);
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A: You don't need `JSON.stringify`, get rid of it. B. Where is `DropDown`?

Comment: do you want to populate the `Members` into the dropdown ??

Comment: Clarified title to better explain problem, re-formatted the code to make the HTML part stand out better, removed fluff from the content. While posting code, please include only the minimal code required. Dumping the entire code can make the question look bigger than it actually is. Sometimes it might be tough to find out what is minimal because you don't know where the problem is but almost 90% of the time tags like head, meta, title etc are not required :)

Answer (score 0):

considering you want to populate `Members` into your dropdown you can use jquery's `each` function to loop through an array.

`each` function takes an array as the paramter.

`$.each(data.Results.Members,function(index,value){
  // here value.Name or value.
})`